# Is there a way to ensure unicode symbols are visible when using kable table within print statement - when knitting to html

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, symbols, kable

I cannot get unicode symbols to show up when knitting a kable table to html, when kable is displayed using print.  Note - I need to use kable within a print statement in order to iterate over a number of sites (kable does not seem to work in a loop without using print).

The unicode symbols display correctly when the kable table is viewed in the Rstudio console directly and when knit when not displayed using knit.

When displayed with print, it displays correctly in the console, but not when knit.  It appears (in html inspector that the unicode characters are converted to <..> when knit.

I have:

- included as results='asis'
- used escape=FALSE in kable()
- used the html equivalent to U+2190 in my table  (e.g. "↑" )

  #----

  ````
   title: "Example of Unicode symbols with kable and print"
   output: html_document
   #----

  #```{r setup, include=FALSE}
  knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
  #```


  #```{r dataset, , include=FALSE}
  library(tidyr)
  library(kableExtra)
  library(purrr)

  dat <- tibble(Symbol=c("up arrow", "down arrow", "side arrows"), 
               htmlCode = c("&#8593;", "&#8595;", "&#8596;"))

  #```


  #```{r kable-tbl, results='asis'}
  tbl_fun <- function(df){
    tbl <- df %>%  kable(escape = F) %>%
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("hover", "condensed"), 
                  full_width = F,  position = "left", fixed_thead = T)

    tbl
  }

  #this works when knit and when run in Rstudio console directly
  tbl_fun(dat)

  #when wrapped in a print function it works when run in Rstudio console directly 
  #but not when knit to html
  print_kable <- function(df) {
          tbl_fun(dat) %>%
              print(format = 'html')
  }

  print_kable(dat)


  #The above was a simplification - in my code I eventually want to iterate over 
  #many parameters, which is why I need to wrap in a print statement....
  #walk(.x = unique(dat$Site), print_kable)
  #```
  ````

Comment: `kable_styling` seems to be converting the strings `"&#8593;"`, `"&#8595;"` and `"&#8596;"` (which render correctly using the `print` method) to the unicode `"←"`, `"↓"`, and `"↔"` which aren't rendered correctly by `print`. I'm not sure why `kable_styling` does this or how you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems `kable_styling()` is escaping the html entities.

The way I found to circumvent this behaviour was to code my html entities as something else, then after all the formatting is done, replace them with their effective codes.

I may for example code `&darr;` as `@darr@`.

Then at the end of my pipe I do the following:

```
kable(...) %>%
    kable_styling(...) %>%
    gsub("@darr@", "&darr;", .) %>%
    cat()
```

It has worked for me.

I have also thought of a more general solution, where I can code any html entity as `&<code>.` and then replace it thus:

```
kable(...) %>%
    kable_styling(...) %>%
    gsub("&([^.]+).", "&\\1;", .) %>%
    cat()
```

However, this doesn't work. It will print `&darr;` (or any other html entity that ends up as a result of the substitution), literally. It seems that in the first case, since "`&darr;`" is mentioned explicitly in the code, it is understood as such. In the latter attempt, since it is generated dynamically, it is not recognized by the markdown parser which has already run before we get to this.

This is so far as I've got. Maybe with more study, a more generic solution could be found.